# Python alsaaudio capturing sound

Tags: python, ubuntu, audio, alsa, pyalsaaudio

I'm trying to capture data from microphone. Code is pretty simple but I get the error `alsaaudio.ALSAAudioError: Capture data too large. Try decreasing period size` for some reason. Tried google it but nothing...

```
res = []

recoder = alsaaudio.PCM(type=alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE)
recoder.setchannels(1)
recoder.setrate(8000)
recoder.setperiodsize(80)
recoder.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S8)

while len(res) < 8000*5:
    len, frame = recoder.read()

    if len(frame) != 0:
        print(len)
        res.extend(frame)
```

The most interesting part is that decreasing doesn't help. But increasing changes the error: period size more than 135 gives me `Input output error`.

OS Ubuntu 16.04. 
Does anybody know what the problem is?

**UPDATE**

Removing recoder.setchannels(1) does the trick and I can set rate/period to 8000/80 and it works but can't set to 8000/10 for example. Got the same error. It seems like a bug.

Comment: Try lowering the rate as well as period to something redicilously low?

Comment: @Torxed 7/1 for rate/period works. 8/1 doesn't. But.. Nothing is printed.

Comment: Do you have to use `alsaaudio`? You could try [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.rtfd.org/) ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all in your code,

```
len, frame = recoder.read()
```

[len](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) is the keyword in python, you can not use it as variable like that.

Otherwise it runs on my laptop OS, no such error you mentioned, but I did face the same issue as you.
What I did is specifying the PCM mode and giving it an appropriate period size.